# BASH: Listening for user input without waiting to do other processes

Tags: linux, bash, input, process, while-loop

Ok so I have a simple script that has the structure down below. I have this sub process that will run for an indefinite amount of time. As of now, it will only stop when the user kills the process manually. I was wondering if there is a way to listen for input from the user without getting stuck on a `read` line. In other words, while the sub process is running, in the background, see if the user types "quit`\n`" in the terminal.

```
...

if [[ option = "3" ]]; then
    while [2 -lt 4]; #THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO CHANGE TO LISTENING FOR INPUT TO QUIT
        #Some sub process that continues to run
    done
fi

....
```

Thanks for the help! Sorry if this is badly worded, I couldn't think of a better way to describe the issue. As for my brainstorming attempts, I know can just use a variable in the `while` condition and say do this until it equals "quit", but setting that variable to the input is where I get lost.

Comment: Does the sub process need to interact with the terminal (i.e. specifically read input and/or produce output)  or is it a process that has a different way of interacting with the user, say for example has an X11 GUI interface?

Comment: @wojtow, no it does not. It prints things out in the terminal, but it does not interact with the user at all. In fact, the user cannot even `Ctrl` + `C` to stop it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but are you looking for something like this?

```
while [[ 2 -lt 4 ]] ; do
        read -t .1 user_input
        [[ ${user_input} == "exit" ]] && exit 0
done
```

or perhaps simpler:

```
unset user_input
while [[ "${user_input}" != "exit" ]] ; do
        read -t .1 user_input
done
```

In general you can probably achieve what you want with `read -t`.

> -t timeout
>                        Cause read to time out and return failure if a complete line of input (or a spec‐
>                        ified number of characters) is not read within timeout seconds.  timeout may be a
>                        decimal  number  with  a  fractional  portion  following the decimal point.  This
>                        option is only effective if read is reading input from a terminal, pipe, or other
>                        special  file;  it  has no effect when reading from regular files.  If read times
>                        out, read saves any partial input read into  the  specified  variable  name.   If
>                        timeout  is  0,  read  returns immediately, without trying to read any data.  The
>                        exit status is 0 if input is available on the specified file descriptor, non-zero
>                        otherwise.  The exit status is greater than 128 if the timeout is exceeded.

Comment: This sounds perfect! Thanks @wisent! Will this work if the sub process takes control of the terminal? The reason I ask is because it is trying to ssh, so I'm not sure if the scope matters. Sorry I'm new to bash! Anyways, thanks for the tip, I'll try it out!